# Combine 2 select statements result sets

Tags: sql, derby

Is there a way to combine the results from 2 select statements in sql? (like Union operator does - but Union works only for same number and type of columns)

I want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM JOBS j 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(fj.Id_Filter) FROM JOBS j LEFT JOIN FILTER_JOBS fj ON j.Id=fj.Id_Job
```

but it doesn't work with UNION

Comment: I do not know any other way than adding a couple of null columns in your first query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AlL of the `select` statements must have the same count of columns, you can do it by adding `null` value column with aliases for example:

```
SELECT cast(null as int) as cnt,col1,col2 FROM JOBS j 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(fj.Id_Filter),null,null FROM JOBS j LEFT JOIN FILTER_JOBS fj ON j.Id=fj.Id_Job
```

You need to put aliases in 1st select statement with cast/converting. In 2nd statement you need include the same count of columns as 1st with `null`.

**EDIT**:

```
SELECT cast(null as int) as cnt,j.* FROM JOBS j 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(fj.Id_Filter),j.* FROM JOBS j LEFT JOIN FILTER_JOBS fj ON j.Id=fj.Id_Job
```

Comment: I see, but i have 54 columns in table JOBS ... so this statement will be pretty ugly with 54 nulls and 54 columns ...

Comment: @fm_strategy Try 2nd solution

Comment: Error: Syntax error: Encountered "*" at line 1, column 33.
SQLState:  42X01
ErrorCode: 30000

Comment: @fm_strategy Try to add `j.*` to 1st select statement as above

Comment: Since `COUNT()` is an aggregate function, in the second solution will you need to put a group by for each of `j`'s fields?

Comment: @Darkzaelus It's not necessary It will count all rows, I hope it's good for OP

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? For me, If I try and execute a `select count (*), * from [table]`, it complains: `Column '[column]' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Darkzaelus Yes its a mistake in my statement i want a count for each job number of filters not a count for all

Comment: @Darkzaelus I'm using tsql

Comment: Hi @fm_strategy, I was just using that as a mockup for my query, please don't worry about it. Parado, I still can't get this to work for me, I run the query with equivalent tables and I still get the error shown above, which version are you running against? I'm using 2005, 2008 and 2012

Comment: @Darkzaelus I'm using sybase and it works, I've checked it on sql server and you have right on SQL Server it doesn't work.

Comment: @fm_strategy What DB are you using?

Comment: i'm using apache derby

Comment: @fm_strategy Could you tell if above selects works separately? Without `union`.

Comment: only the first query works separateley. but when i run them together, i get the error at the first query, not the second

Comment: @fm_strategy What do you want to count? All rows in table `JOBS` ?

Comment: no, i want to count the number of filters for each job. i want an output in result set like this:

Comment: 1 job1 ... ... .. 5 //matches 5 filters

Comment: @fm_strategy So from firts query you need all column and from 2nd query you want to only `jobfilter` and `coutn` columns?

Comment: yes, i want all the columns from the first query and an additional column which counts the number of filters for each job

Comment: @fm_strategy I'm afraid it's not possible without specifying all columns